# Help I cant understand difference set and bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm proving this problem and I have no idea to solve so, I looked solution on the book. But this makes me so confused.

Here is the problem.

For two sets $X$ and $Y$, If $(X-Y) \sim (Y-X)$ then $X \sim Y$.
(where $X \sim Y $ means there exist one-to-one correspondence for sets $X$ and $Y$)

and here is the solution.

Let $f$ : $X - Y \sim Y - X \quad $ and   $\quad g : X \to Y, \quad $
$g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if  $\quad x$ $\in$ X-Y} \\
x, & \text{if $\quad x$ $\in$ $X \cap Y$}
\end{cases}$

I can understand this definition of function $g$ shows bijection, but I cant understand why $\quad g(x)=x\quad$  where $x \in X \cap Y $.

Is there any guarantee that the function $g$ could be $g(x)=x$?

Let me know WHY THE FUNCTION $\quad g \quad$  has to have that appearance or any other solution of this problem.

Comment: "why the function $g$ has to have that appearance.." It does not have to. There are more possibilities. Finding one of them is enough to conclude that $X\sim Y$.

Comment: sorry not $x \in X \cup Y$ , $x \in X \cap Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does there exist a function $h:X\cap Y\to Y$ that is prescribed by $x\mapsto x$?

Yes, because for every $x\in X\cap Y$ (i.e. for every $x$ in domain $X\cap Y$) we have $x\in Y$ (i.e. $x$ is an element of codomain $Y$).

Next to that from the fact that $X-Y\sim Y-X$ it follows that we have a function $k:X-Y\to Y$ such that $k$ is injective and its image is the set $Y-X$.

Based on these functions $h$ and $k$ we construct the function $g:X\to Y$.

It is prescribed by $x\mapsto k(x)$ if $x\in X-Y$ and $x\mapsto g(x)=x$ if $x\in X\cap Y$.

It is not difficult to prove that $g$ is a bijection justifying the conclusion that $X\sim Y$.

Comment: Oh God. you're so genius!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to find is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$.  The claim here is that $g$ is such a bijection.  It only needs to take values from $X$ (and return values from $Y$), it does not need to take values from $Y$.

The situation is symmetric and you could just as easily find a function from $Y$ to $X$ but you don't need to find one from $X \cup Y$ to anywhere.  (This comment is now unnecessary since the question has been edited from  "why $g(x)=x$  where $x \in X \cup Y $" to "$ g(x)=x$  where $x \in X \cap Y $".)

A concrete example might help.  Our universe consists of people with either black or white trousers and either black or white shirts.  Consider that $X$ is the set of people with black trousers and $Y$ is the set of people with black shirts.

$X - Y$ is the set of people with black trousers and white shirts.

$Y - X$ is the set of people with black shirts and white trousers.

We are told that there is a bijection between these two.  We don't know or need to know the details just that it exists.  We call this bijection $f$. It takes values in $X - Y$ but maybe not all of $X$ and gives values $Y - X$ but maybe not all of $Y$.

The bit of $X$ that $f$ might not be defined for is $X \cap Y$ and the bit of $Y$ that is not covered by $f$ is $Y \cap X$.  Conveniently, these are the same as $\cap$ is commutative.  So, we can use it to define our new function $g$ on this subset very simply.

So, back to our concrete example.

$X$ is the set of people of people with black trousers and either colour of shirt.
$Y$ is the set of people of people with black shirts and either colour of trousers.

We need map $X$ to $Y$.

$X$ splits into $X \cap Y$ (black trousers and black shirts) and $X - Y$ (black trousers and white shirts).

The first part are also in $Y$ so we can map them to themselves (second line of the definition of $g$).

The second is covered by the bijection that we are told exists.  Somehow, we can map $X - Y$ (black trousers and white shirts) to $Y - X$ (white trousers and black shirts).

Can you see that this is a bijection?

**Why?**

Sorry, I failed to answer the why at the end of your question.

We are asked to find *a* bijection between $X$ and $Y$, not *the* bijection.  The distinction I am making is that there is not necessarily just one.  In fact, it is very unlikely that there is a single bijection. That would happen only in the case that both $X$ and $Y$ had a single element.  Even if they are small finite sets (but more than one element) then there will be lots of bijections.  So, there is no claim that $g$ is the only answer.  It is just that  $g$ is an easy answer and one answer is enough.

This is a tough part of mathematics.  It is often easy to understand someone else's proof but it is still hard to understand how they thought of it. With practice, this type of example should become easy but many others will remain hard.  For example, when Andrew Wiles proved Fermat's Last Theorem, I don't think that anyone said: "that was obvious, why didn't I think of that".

Comment: The OP writes that he does understand that his $g$ is a bijection, but doesn't understand why it has been given the definition it has in the first place. That seems to hint of some deeper misunderstanding about the nature of mathematics.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes but I was hoping that my concrete example would help.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I added bit more.  I'll wait to see whether the OP responds.

Comment: My answer initially addressed "why $g(x)=x$  where $x \in X \cup Y $" but just as I started to suspect it was a typo, the OP changed it to "$ g(x)=x$  where $x \in X \cap Y $".  So, it was.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear that $g$ has to have this definition. However, that is not the initial question. The task is to provide a bijection $g:X\to Y$ and we've found one. There may be more, but that is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I have other question in your answer. You said "he task is to provide a bijection g:X→Y". Is it correct that I understand this as I can choose any type of bijection function to prove? I think this way is not general becuase I choose specific one to prove. Choose any type of bijection is guaranteed?

Comment: @SeunghwanShin it depends on how you define $\sim$. Usually it's said that $A\sim B$ iff there exists a bijection $A\to B$. Defining any bijection $A\to B$ is sufficient to prove.

Answer (score 0):

$g:x\mapsto x$ when $x\in X\cap Y$ is *clearly* a bijection, $X\cap Y\mapsto Y\cap X$.   So by choosing this, no further work needs to be done in that partition.

You are told that some $f$ exists where $x\mapsto f(x)$ is a bijection for $(X\smallsetminus Y) \mapsto (Y\smallsetminus X)$ too.

Thus by choosing such a $g$ that has those pieces over those partitions, you have *constructed* a bijection $g: X\mapsto Y$.